# Redirecting 404s from Deleted CPTs

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to redirect 404s for a custom post type no longer available on my site ('profile'). There are plenty of plugins and questions about doing this for posts/pages but I've yet to find some direction on doing this for CPTs. Anyone?

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to redirect all /profile/ pages to the same place, or is there some redirect logic you need to apply?